# Magento 2 core functionalities and structure - difference between vendor/magento/framework and vendor/magento/module-* namespace code?

Tags: magento2, code

What is the difference and when to use `vendor/magento/framework` code, and when to use the `vendor/magento/module-*` code?

Answer (score 4):

Under the `vendor/magento/framework` folder, magento 2 is keeping its core logic, the basic functionalities which are widely used in the rest of the modules under the `vendor/magento/module-*`/.

For example take a look in `vendor/magento/framework/Url.php` class and you will find methods as `getUrl()` or `getCurrentUrl()`. Or in `vendor/magento/framework/Registry.php` class, at `registry($key)`, `register($key, $value, $graceful = false)`, `unregister($key)` methods.